# jQuery Sticky Scroller Multiple instances

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm trying to use the plugin [(http://www.vertstudios.com/blog/jquery-sticky-scroller-position-fixed-plugin](http://www.vertstudios.com/blog/jquery-sticky-scroller-position-fixed-plugin)) on a page i'm building. I'm wanting to use the function more than once on the page but I've found that if I call it more than once, only the 2nd instance works correctly. The other does not smoothly exit the fixed position. I've got a feeling that the plugin is using an absolute position for the last element.

Example code...

```
var scroller1 = new StickyScroller(“#text1″,
{
start: 2145,
end: 3000,
interval: 300,
range: 100,
margin: 680
});

var scroller2 = new StickyScroller(“#text2″,
{
start: 7145,
end: 7600,
interval: 300,
range: 100,
margin: 680
});
```

Thanks in advanced.

PVS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the author of said StickyScroller plugin. Honestly, I think the plugin is a piece of crap, I made it a couple of years ago when I was relatively new to jQuery. The only good thing it has going for it is some stupidly messy ways of getting the "stickyness" to work in IE7. I highly recommend using [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) for your "sticky" needs. It's much more elegant and concise than my plugin.

Comment: Haha! Cheers pal. It was doing the job for what I needed apart from multiple instances. It's far better than anything I could conger up!

Comment: That's hysterical. Thanks Joe for your work and recommendation. :D